# Insert python list elements in HTML <img> tag

Tags: python, html, list, image

I am writing a code that I want to use to plot points on a map and insert a corresponding picture with a description. Among other things, the name of the place should be displayed below the image. I have stored the different names in Python as strings in a list.

```
names = ['location1', 'location2', 'location3']
```

I create the images in a foor loop like this:

```
for i in (range(len(df))):
        points = kml.newpoint(description='''<img src="path_to_picture.jpg" width="400" height="250"/><br><font size="+1" font color="black">Name</font>''', coords=[(df['longitude'].iloc[i], df['latitude'].iloc[i], df['altitude'].iloc[i])])
```

The  length of my dataframe 'df' and my list 'names' is equal.

Can I refer to my list in the img tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is probably with an `f-string`

This can be done as an example seen below:

`f"Name: {name_variable}"` becomes `f"Name: Harry"` when interpreted.

In your case, as your list is the same length as the dataframe, and you have index you could replace your string with the following:

`f"<img src="path_to_picture.jpg" width="400" height="250"/><br><font size="+1" font color="black">{names[i]}</font>"`